# Best-fit relative orientations and locations of stereo cameras

Tags: computer-vision, computational-geometry

I have 2 static cameras being used for stereo 3D positioning of objects. I need to determine the location and orientation of the second camera relative to the first as accurately as possible. I am trying to do this by locating n objects on the both cameras' images and correlating between the two cameras in order to calibrate my system to locate additional objects later.

Is there a preferred way to use a large number (6+) of correlated points to determine the best-fit relative locations/orientations of 2 cameras, assuming that I have already compensated for any distortive effects and know the correct (but somewhat noisy) angles between the optical axes and the objects, and the distance between the cameras?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to determine a rotation to perform on the second camera (B) in order to realign its measurements so they are from the point of view of the first camera (A) as if it has been translated to the location of camera B.

I did this using a compound rotation by first rotating the second camera's measurements about the cross product of vector -AB (B pointing at A from the perspective of A) and BA (B pointing at A from the perspective from B) such that R1*BA=-AB. Doing this rotation just means the vectors pointing between the cameras are aligned, and another rotation must be done in order to account for further degrees of freedom.

That rotation was done so that the second one can be *about* -AB. R2 is a rotation of theta radians about -AB. I found theta by taking the cross products of my measurements from camera A and vector AB, and comparing them to the cross products of R1*(the measurements from camera B) and -AB. I numerically minimized the RMS of the angles between the cross product pairs, because when the cameras are aligned those cross product vectors should be all pointing in the same directions because they are normal to coplanar planes.

After that I can use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/finding-the-intersection-point-of-many-lines-in-3d-point-closest-to-all-lines to find accurate 3D locations of intersection points by applying R1*R2 to any future measurements from camera B.